# Apache Maven get server password by executing external command

Tags: maven, aws-codeartifact

AWS CodeArtifact, for example, authenticates with a token valid for 12 hours. A typical setup of maven with CodeArtifact is:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>my-domain--my-repo</id>
    <username>aws</username>
    <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

in settings.xml and executing

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=$(
      aws codeartifact get-authorization-token \
            --domain my-domain \
            --domain-owner 123456789012 \
            --query authorizationToken \
            --output text
)
```

in terminal every 12 hours before invoking mvn.

I thought I could have:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>my-domain--my-repo</id>
    <username>aws</username>
    <password>${codeartifact.auth.token}</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

in settings.xml and then have a

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <properties>
          <script>aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my-domain --domain-owner 123456789012 --query authorizationToken --output text</script>
        </properties>
        <source>
          def command = project.properties.script
          def process = command.execute()
          process.waitFor()

          def token = process.in.text.trim()

          project.properties.setProperty('codeartifact.auth.token', token)
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

section in pom.xml to automate CodeArtifact token retrieval.

Except it didn't work. I wonder if the idea I have is valid altogether and what didn't work is just implementation flaw. Or is it just not possible to have this kind of automation with maven.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? We are also looking for an integration of AWS CodeArtifact and want to automate the process of getting the authorization token.

Answer (score 0):

1. macOS

   ```
   launchctl setenv CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN $(aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain your-codeartifact-domain --domain-owner 12345678 --region your-codeartifact-region --query authorizationToken --output text --profile your-profile-if-needed)
   ```
2. Windows

   ```
   setx CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN $(aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain your-codeartifact-domain --domain-owner 12345678 --region your-codeartifact-region --query authorizationToken --output text --profile your-profile-if-needed)
   ```

This makes the CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN env var available to all new processes (such as IDEs) from that point until it expires. Maven will resolve `${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}` properly.

I assume Linux users know how to set up their `.profile` or equivalent.